# Junit gets stuck even before Junit Test classes are loaded

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running a codebuild using mvn build to run Java integ test

The mvn build got stuck at below point

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running Test1
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.501 s - in Test1
[INFO] Running Test2
```

Now by trial and error I removed some unused libraries imports and the Test cases proceeded and started working fine.

To debug why its getting stuck with those unused library imports I added

```
    static
    {
        log.warn(() ->"Good news class is getting loaded");
    }

also added logs in static methods.
```

And reverted back the fix and saw if there issue even before class is loaded , and yes I was not able to see those static logs messages.I feel there is issue with maven or Junit while running the Test2

My question is

How can I debug this issue , why is the Maven build getting stuck when I add those unused libraries ? How can I root cause this ?

Comment: A thread dump would be useful to see where the process is blocked: https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump

Comment: Issue is recreated only in aws Codebuild , could you please let me know how to capture thread dump while mvn build is in progress and stuck in codebuild.

Comment: I don't know too much about CodeBuild, but this documentation shows a way to connect to a running build container: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/session-manager.html. Then I would expect the techniques from the article I linked to before to work (e.g., `jstack` command or `kill -3`).